# How to store small images in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab

I am attempting to convert a 1x8 array into an image, I know that the resulting image would be tiny. I do that using the following code:

```
filename = fullfile('/Users/jlmontalvo/Documents/MATLAB/train_data.csv');
T = readtable(filename);

C1 = [];
t = T(1,:);
a = t.Variables;
a(end) = []; %getting rid of the last value
test = getimage(imshow(a, [])); %display image
imwrite(test,'/Users/jlmontalvo/Desktop/hello.png'); %store image
```

the issue is that the image that MATLAB displays looks like this:

[image: displayed image]

but the one that is actually saved is completely different and looks like this:

[image: saved image, which is different]

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getimage` gets the data displayed. That is, after

```
test = getimage(imshow(a, []));
```

`test` is identical to `a`.

You are showing the image with contrast stretch, making the smallest value black and the largest value white. But retrieving the data from those axes does not take any of that into account, it simply returns the displayed data.

Instead, you could stretch the data yourself:

```
test = double(a);
test = test - min(test(:));
test = test / max(test(:));
```

Comment: DO you know how would I go about doing this for an 8x8 array? I attempted just doing the same code, but it just gives me a vertical 8x1 image @Cris Luengo

Comment: @JoseMontalvo: I’ve edited the answer to work with arbitrary images.